# Why YouTube looks different on Safari

Tags: website-design, browser, page-layout, chrome

I am a Mac user and Chrome is my default browser.

I think to give Safari a try and after using for some time I realise that YouTube looks different on safari compare to Chrome.

Here is a small list of some of the changes:

[image]

I tried to search it online and found some answer but not anything convincing.

- Some say because its different browser but it looks same on Firefox and Opera why only different on Safari? And some changes are not possible due to browser difference.
- Some say Chrome is the product of Google that's why. But What about other browsers?
- Some suggest that it is because of giving Mac user a different experience. But what if I am using Chrome on Mac?

From changes it is very clear that this are intentional change not because of any bug or platform change.

Is there any UI/UX advantage like smoothness in Safari or Same design is not possible (Or hard to implement) for Safari? Or something else which I totally miss?

Comment: Are both windows the same actual size? Are you logged with the same account? Can you post pictures of the two versions of the same page as you see them?

Comment: Yes both window are same size and same account. This is how it look on Safari for me: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bw3426eto98m8md/Screen%20Shot%202018-09-08%20at%2010.57.40%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: Please edit your question to include both screenshots (as images, not links). You wouldn’t have applied some form of zoom on any of the windows, would you?

Comment: You are looking at the older version of YouTube, because your browser could have cached certain webiste preferences. I'd try clearing your cache or checking the YouTube settings if I were you.

Comment: If you’re seeing an older YouTube design, as @Levano said, it can also be, that you’re using an old Safari, which doesn’t support the latest YouTube version. What are your macOS and Safari versions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you'll have to ask Youtube designers to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, I'm seeing (virtually) identical designs on Chrome and Safari. Chances are they may just be running split-tests and you happen to get that version in one browser and not the others (cookies are not persistent across browsers).

Comment: Here is how it looks on my Safari: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bw3426eto98m8md/Screen%20Shot%202018-09-08%20at%2010.57.40%20AM.png?dl=0 and I am getting this interface from al most a month.